# Xcode 8 beta 4 crashes every time when opening .sks file

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, beta

I'm trying to start a new Xcode project in the beta 4 with the game template but I can't get rid of the "Hello" label because it seems to be hidden in one of the .sks files.

Problem: Xcode 8 will crash every single time I try to open an .sks file.

Any solution to this, other than waiting for the next beta?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There is no solution. :( We can only waite for the next beta. :)

Comment: It works again in beta 5.